# Missing updated parent entities (with cascade={"persist"}) and correct stored new child entities with Doctrine flush and a batchsize > 1

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**Context**

I'm using the current doctrine version together with Symfony.

I have two entities. Entity A has an FK to entity B via `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\B", cascade={"persist", "remove"})`.

**Process**

1. I fetch a list of entity A from DB
2. In a loop for each entity A, I create a new entity B and set them via `$a->setB($b)`
3. Persist entity A with `$em->persist($a);`
4. Finally, I want to perform the flush & clear only every 100 loops by

```
$batchSize = 10;
 if ($i % $batchSize === 0) {
   $this->em->flush();
   $this->em->clear();
 }
```

**Expect**

I expect now in DB an INSERT for new entities B and an update for entity A with the ID of each entity B.

**Problem/Error**

If I set my batch size to 1, everything works well (but slow).

But, if the batch size is >1, only the last changed entity A gets a DB-update. The doctrine logs the DB statements look like this (here with batch size 2). Only for the last INSERT of entity B, I got an UPDATE of entity A.

```
[2020-06-03T16:31:30.757252+03:00] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO B (...) VALUES (...) {...} []
[2020-06-03T16:31:30.758809+03:00] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO B (...) VALUES (...) {...} []
[2020-06-03T16:31:30.759844+03:00] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE A SET B_id = ? WHERE id = ? [521509,3] []
```

Does someone know how to solve this? I also tried only to persist entity B or both, but no luck...

Many thx and Gtx

Comment: Maybe you should also persist B objects?

Comment: @Leprechaun As I wrote, I also tried this. I've also seen while debugging doctrine code, that in cascade persit case, while persit A also B is stored. As also the SQL-logs shows. The question is, why/how I can ensure, that for every B (INSERT) the corresponding A (UPDATE) gets the update with B-Id in its FK-field?

Comment: Try changing relation to move the foreign key (B_id) to class B. So you will have A_id in B table. Use `@JoinColumn` annotation to do it.
I think I had a similar issue, and problem was on the moment of persistence doctrine has no ID from B class. ID field is autoincrement and gets created only after flushing.